# Opencv replace colored circle with image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am very new to opencv (with background of android, .net). I am testing opencv on windows(in c++) , if it worked i will move it to android.

**Scenario:**

I have a image this one :
[image]

I want to replace the red circle with another image (face of another person).

I have successfully detected red circle and able to draw another circle with this code:

```
Mat orig_image = cv::imread("testimg3.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
Mat outImg;
double alpha = 0.5; double beta; double input;

if (orig_image.empty()){
    cout << "No Image found." << endl;
    return -1;
}
// Convert input image to HSV
cv::cvtColor(orig_image, outImg, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

// Threshold the HSV image, keep only the red pixels
Mat lower_red_hue_range;
Mat upper_red_hue_range;
inRange(outImg, cv::Scalar(0,100,100), cv::Scalar(10, 255, 255), lower_red_hue_range);
inRange(outImg, cv::Scalar(160, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(179, 255, 255), upper_red_hue_range);

cv::Mat red_hue_image;
cv::addWeighted(lower_red_hue_range, 1.0, upper_red_hue_range, 1.0, 0.0, red_hue_image);


// Use the Hough transform to detect circles in the combined threshold image
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
cv::HoughCircles(red_hue_image, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, red_hue_image.rows / 8, 100, 20, 100, 1000);

if (circles.size() == 0) std::exit(-1);
    for (size_t current_circle = 0; current_circle < circles.size(); ++current_circle) {
            cv::Point center(std::round(circles[current_circle][0]), std::round(circles[current_circle][1]));
            int radius = std::round(circles[current_circle][2]);
    cv::circle(orig_image, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),CV_FILLED,8,0); //cv::circle(orig_image, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),5);

}
```

**My goal:**
my goal is to draw an image in place of circle.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Get the `centroid` of your detected circle, `area/radius`, `origin coordinate` and then transform the new face to plot it there

Comment: @FirstStep as i said i am very new to this, can you post the code ? i have center and radius of circle. (thanks for help)

Comment: I don't have a code Hamza.. But I could help you in the design and you should give it a try. Search google for each sentence: Get center of the new image, crop image based on radius, plot an image on top of another image (or How to `AND` two images)

Comment: ok thank for guidance